# ¿Como puedo desactivar la función onLocationChanged() en AndroidStudio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo una app que estoy realizando, necesito habilitar una función a un boton que se encargue de parar el metodo onLocationChanged(); o sea, que yo al darle click al boton, la aplicación deje de enviar las coordenadas a tráves del GPS

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, recuerda realizar tus preguntas en base al documento [ask] para que obtengas la ayuda requerida en el sitio, te sugerimos editar tu pregunta, agrega lo que has realizado. No olvides realizar el [tour] del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes cambiar en el "MyLocationManager" lo siguiente:

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(myLL);
```